# Spring Autowiring error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method [name] can only contain 1 method field. Found: [PUT, POST]

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-cloud-feign

I have a method in one of my webservices that accepts both PUT and POST. This is because we started using PUT but later we needed to support POST too (for a new service).

> ```
> @RequestMapping(
>         value = "/endpointURL",
>         method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST})
> ```

I am trying to create a test application that calls this method, but Spring throws an Autowiring error during startup with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method [name] can only contain 1
>   method field. Found: [PUT, POST]

Both the Spring and Feign versions are the same in both applications (webservice with this endpoint, and testing application).

Any ideas on how to fix it please?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. I dount it is Spring MVC but rather Feign that requires a single method (else how should it know what to pick).

Answer (score 0):

Method supports various HTTP method as below. Could you post your class source code. I think you should have another problem. Maybe duplicated path or else.

```
@RequestMapping("/v1/echo")
@RestController
public class EchoApi {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<String> echo(@RequestBody String body){
        System.err.println(body);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was due to the Feign version we were using. It's fixed after version 10. Will close this topic. Thanks!